# Реальный рейтинг пользователя

Tags: обсуждение, статистика, data-explorer

Возможно ли как-то узнать свой или чужой рейтинг с учетом тех пользователей, которые заблокированы модераторами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне известно что есть пользователи с достаточно высоким рейтингом, при этом заблокированные, когда они будут разблокированы - цифры на скриншоте изменятся.

Вопрос - есть ли возможность узнать реальные цифры?

Comment: С помощью https://data.stackexchange.com или API можно)

Comment: нашел вот такой запрос, но он идентичен странице рейтинга... https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/6772/stackoverflow-rank-and-percentile

Comment: @Suvitruf, разве на DataSE репутация не оединичивается на время бана? Вроде там так забаненных искали, что есть сообщения с голосами, а репутация 1.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно сложить все голоса за ответы/вопросы и самому посчитать реальный рейтинг пользователя.

Comment: @Suvitruf не совсем, т.к. не все голоса дают рейтинг и не весь рейтинг от голосов

Comment: @StrangerintheQ https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1055972/total-rep-of-user-even-for-blocked можете для [Athari](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176051/athari?tab=topactivity) посчитать. Выдаёт 26590.

Comment: узнать точную репутацию заблокированного можно по графику в профиле - там есть тултип со значением репутации

Comment: @PashaPash это не поможет узнать свою позицию. Разве что, вы в профиль к каждому заблокированному пользователю зайдёте и ручками таблицу оформите )

Comment: @Suvitruf да, поэтому это комментарий, а не ответ. но вообще - у нас не так много заблокированных с высоким рейтингом, чтобы ручной проход занял много времени

Comment: @PashaPash да, но они должны быть мне известны..

Comment: в общем то это не важно, просто стало интересно, я думал может быть есть простой способ

Comment: @Suvitruf, зачем ручками, если можно автоматизировать?

Comment: @PashaPash ничего. Скоро будет больше модераторов, можно будет больше народу забанить :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для конкретного пользователя можно [таким запросом](https://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/1055972/total-rep-of-user-even-for-blocked) посчитать +- точную репутацию. Для того же [Athari](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176051/athari?tab=topactivity) выдаёт `26590`.

Можно попробовать это завернуть в `SELECT` по каждому пользователю и подзапросом посчитать и отсортировать по рейтингу. Но https://data.stackexchange.com с таким запросом не справляется, падает по таймауту.

Можно дамп данных себе скачать и локально выполнить запрос, повысив лимиты на локальной машине на выполнение запросов.

Comment: да, такой не быстрый способ, но все же спасибо

Comment: Только у него 26367 в профиле написано.

Comment: @Qwertiy числа немного не точные, да =/